# Out of memory when booting

Tags: linux, boot, grub, out-of-memory

I have a dual boot system and am running [Elementary OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_OS) in one partition and Windows 10 in another. I received an update for the Linux kernel and applied it, but then my computer was not able to boot Elementary nor Windows.

A `> grub rescue` message appears when I turn on my PC. Then I find for partition with vmlinuz and execute

```
set prefix=(hd0,msdos7)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
```

With this I can see my GRUB menu and try to boot with one of my operating systems

When I try to boot with Linux it shows:

> Kill process... Out of memory...

When I try to boot with Windows it stays loading.

I've tried to boot with a Linux Live USB, but the Linux error message is still there.

I've tried to boot with Windows USB and it keeps loading.

I have 8 GB of RAM and 1 TB SATA HDD. I've tried to boot from another HDD in my computer and it works, but I am not able to see my principal HDD. I've extracted the CMOS battery, and it didn't work. What should I do?

What could be the problem? Should I buy a new HDD?

Comment: I would be inclined to suggest the issue is with your RAM, not your HDD. My reasoning comes from the fact a LiveCD doesn't boot. Run a RAM test.

Comment: But I can boot with another HDD. I'll run the RAM test.